# What are extensions, extension count and layer count in vulkan/opengl

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

As the title says what are extensions?
For example, What does this chunk of code do specifically?

```
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};

unint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
const char** glfwExtensions;

glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;
createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

[TFM](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__vulkan.html#ga99ad342d82f4a3421e2864978cb6d1d6):

> This function returns an array of names of Vulkan instance extensions required by GLFW for creating Vulkan surfaces for GLFW windows. If successful, the list will always contain `VK_KHR_surface`, so if you don't require any additional extensions you can pass this list directly to the `VkInstanceCreateInfo` struct.
>
> [...]

There's no layer count in glfw, only in Vulkan.

Extensions extend the Vulkan API with additional optional functionality. Vulkan is by default headless, so presenting output to the OS Surface via the Swapchain is one such extension.

Layers introduce hooks to the Vulkan API calls that can be intercepted and changed before the function call gets to the graphics driver. It for example allows to intercept the Vulkan calls and check if you passed correct parameters. Or perhaps a layer can add a FPS counter to the output.

`glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions` is [only a Vulkan specific function](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__vulkan.html), and it won't be used with OpenGL